# How to set the background image below the toolbar?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, background, toolbar

i am working on android studio, after i set a toolbar i noticed it came over the background and ruining it. is there a way to lower the background ?

i don't know what to try. i don't know what to do

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    ></include>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsnrB.png)

Comment: add an image of that layout for better understanding.

Comment: i uploaded an image.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.admin.booking.BookingActivity">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/iv_parking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_layout">
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```